# How to check the commit id of the checkout file in Git?

Tags: git, version, commit

Assuming I have three commits for file a.txt in my repository:

```
>git log -- a.txt
commit 63cfed7cebe84009aa4fba6e4a62ea5b0bec7660
commit 874028c921f22e0c3e44d0faf13eef2b7638d3ff
commit 0a89b0751afdb111ba775922e85bbac6302f727c
```

Then I issue the commmand

```
>git checkout 874028c921f22e0c3e44d0faf13eef2b7638d3ff  a.txt
```

to checkout the file a.txt back to v1.

Suppose later I forget which commit the working version of a.txt was checked out from. Is there a command that I can use to determine that information?

I have tried the following:

```
>git log --a.txt
```

It shows all the commit log of this file.

```
>git status 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
      modified:   a.txt
```

But all these are not what I want. I need to see the current version a.txt is in. Then what cmd I can use to determine the commit_id of current a.txt ?

Comment: `git log --stat`?

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose later I forget which commit the working version of a.txt was checked out from. Is there a command that I can use to determine that information?

No (but see [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43598791/1256452) for a relatively fast way to search for *some* commit that has a file of the same name that matches the index version; that may be close enough).  There are several reasons for this:

- Git does keep track of your *current commit*.  That's simply `HEAD`.  But it doesn't keep track of one commit per work-tree file.
- For that matter, a work-tree file is too hard to keep track of in the first place.  Programs, or editors, or people, are constantly changing them.
- Meanwhile, for every file extracted from some commit, Git has an "original copy" of that file in your *index*.  Your index, to summarize it very briefly, is *where you build your **next** commit*.  If you have modified a file in your work-tree and want the *new* version to go in your next commit, you `git add` the file to copy the new version into the index.  Otherwise, the index still holds the old version.

The version of the file that is in the index *does* have a hash ID, similar to commit hash IDs.  (In fact, commit and file, or *blob*, objects in Git have their hash IDs computed the same way.  The same is true for Git's two other internal object types.)  But while the hash ID of a *commit* is unique to that commit, the hash ID of a *file version* is *not* unique to one particular commit.

Consider, for instance, the sequence:

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp && git init
```

(now we have a new, empty temporary directory to hold a new repository)

```
echo a README > README
git add README
echo initial version > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m initial
```

This new Git repository has one commit, with two files in it, `README` and `file.txt`.  Your index also has two files in it, `README` and `file.txt`.  Now we modify `file.txt` and commit the new one:

```
echo more data >> file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m 'added more'
```

Your repository now has *two* commits.  The second commit has the *same* `README` file in it as the first commit.  The file is stored exactly once, under its "blob" hash, and the two different commits (and the index) all use the *same* hash ID to say "that version of that data".

In fact, if we now *rename* the `README` file:

```
git mv README README.md
git commit -m 'rename README'
```

we now have *three* commits, and *all three of them* (and the index) share a single version of the blob object.  The latest commit calls that blob object `README.md`, while the two earlier ones call it `README`, but all three have the same hash ID.

There is a minor technical reason Git *can't* store the hash ID of the commit from which the index version of some blob-hash was extracted: when you do:

```
git checkout <hash> -- <path>
```

Git translates the `<hash>` part to a *tree* hash, rather than a *commit* hash (and in fact you can just give it the hash ID of a tree object).  So it doesn't necessarily have a specific commit hash in the first place.  This is also why the syntax in the help / documentation reads:

> `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>...]`

The `<tree-ish>` means that Git doesn't demand a commit ID at all; if you give it one, it finds the corresponding `<tree>` object (which may be shared among several or many commits).

All that said, if you want, you *can* find the hash ID of some path name stored in your index:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

shows them all, and you can use `git rev-parse` to find individual ones.  You can then, if you like, search some or all of your commits, find their tree objects, read those trees, and search them for that hash.  If you find the hash in some tree or trees, you can then say that the index version of the file appears in those commits under those path names.

Hence, given the hash of `README.md` in the index for the repository above, we could search all three commits, read their trees, and find that what is currently in the index as `README.md` matches what is stored as `README` in two commits and `README.md` in the current (HEAD) commit.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.

Comment: @buddha: I added a link to jthill's answer, which might serve your purposes (hard to tell since it's not clear what your purpose might be).

Answer (score 1):

With git hash-object you can find the SHA1 of the a.txt that you have in your working tree.

```
git hash-object a.txt
```

Then search through all the git commits to find the particular object SHA1

```
for rev in $(git rev-list --all); do git ls-tree -r $rev | grep -q <SHA1> && echo $rev ; done
```

This will give you a list of commits with your current version of a.txt. The last line in this resulting list will be the first commit that had your current version of a.txt

Answer (score 1):

Given your conditions, yes, it's not hard:

```
find=$(git rev-parse :a.txt)   # as staged i.e. last checked out or added
for commit in $(git rev-list @ -- a.txt); do 
        [[ $(git rev-parse $commit:a.txt) = $find ]] && { echo $commit; break; }
done
```

will print the commit that introduced the version you're looking for.

As @torek points out, (a) the index records the id of whatever you last checked out or added (or set with some core command) at that path, so doing any of those others means you can't hunt for what was there before; and (b) in your example at least every commit in the 874028..63cfed~ range also has that same `a.txt` content, so you *could* have checked it out from any of those, too.  But if you did do what's shown and are operating in some benighted environment that can't just `^Rcheckout` or otherwise recall/edit commands with no fuss, you can use the above snippet.